# How can one update environmental variables in HIVE from R?

Tags: r, jdbc, hive, amazon-emr

I would like to use Hive environmental variables to leverage the value of views within Hive and to set the priority of my Hive queries.  The way I've seen to do this is in the form of the command `set mapred.job.priority=VERY_LOW`.

I connect to Hive and generate my queries at run-time from R connecting via `RJDBC` package.  When I use `dbSendUpdate` to send the command above I receive the following error message:

```
execute JDBC update query failed in dbSendUpdate ([Simba][JDBC](11320) A RowCount was expected but not generated from query "set mapred.job.priority=VERY_LOW". Query not executed. )
```

Is there a way to send these environmental variable setting commands to Hive via R?

**Details and versions:**

- I'm using Amazon's HIVE drivers to connect to a EMR Release 4.1 cluster on AWS
- Hive 1.0.0
- R Version 3.2.2
- RJDBC version 0.2-5
- DBI version 0.3.1

Comment: Hi rpierce, which version of the Amazon Hive JDBC drivers are you using (forgive me if it's noted above as it's not obvious to me).

Comment: It looks like JDBC3_1.0.0; I see they are up to 1.0.4, I'll give that a try and post here with results.

Comment: Upgrading solved the issue, since you prompted me to try that, feel free to post as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the version you were using, 1.0.0, did not support this and it's since been added to 1.0.4.